# Error while running 'ionic run android'

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native, ionic3

I have a native android application which is currently available in Play store. Now i have developed same application with new features in Ionic 3. For testing purpose, i have debug version of native app installed in my device. Now when i run `ionic run android` command, it gives me error as below.

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

Below is my config for both app.

## Native App

1. package-name : com.myapp
2. version : 1.7
3. versionCode : 7

## Ionic App

1. package-name : com.myapp
2. version : 2.0
3. versionCode : 8

Because i want to update same application, i have put package-name same for both application.

**Note: *I have debug version of native app installed in device, so it's not the case like i'm trying to update release version of native app with debug version of ionic app.***

Another question is, can i access native application database in ionic application? If yes, then how?

Comment: What is your native application database?

Answer (score 0):

you can keep both by changing app Id that is like `com.example.appname`

at the time of submission you can restore app id to original

Comment: In config.xml of ionic app you can change package name ie. com.myapp

Comment: But it will not update my native app instead it will install new application. That's not what i want. Because later i want to move all the database data from native app to ionic app. If there will be both seperate applications then i can't access database of native app.